# How to make several methods one transaction in asp.net MVC using EF

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to execute 2 Actions and make them atomic.
This is what I want to achieve:

```
public IActionResult DataUserForm()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Handler(data)
{
    /*
        Do something with data
    */
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

DataUserForm View sends a Form to User where he can write some data. Then he is redirected to Handler, that does some business logic and redirects to Index homePage. I want to make all this Actions a transaction

There is already BeginTransaction() method in EF. But it can only be used with specific block of code and not in the methods. I also can not pass transaction as a parameter to action, because there are some problems with submit buttons and c# object

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. In a web service, each web request is in its own scope. Why do you want to try and keep a scope open inbetween to separate web requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DbContext is a [scoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scoped) service, so you have a single instance per web request.